# PHP combine two multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use array_combine to combine two multi-dimensional arrays, but somehow not doing it correctly.

Here is array1:

```
Array(
    [Nov 18, 2011] => Array(
        [C] => 107705.5792
        [I] => 44561.52
    )
    [Nov 22, 2011] => Array(
        [C] => -8992.8352
    )
)
```

and here is array2:

```
Array(
    [Nov 18, 2011] => Array(
        [C] => 3
        [I] => 1
    )
    [Nov 22, 2011] => Array(
        [C] => 2
    )
)
```

Here is my attempt at array_combine, which is not working:

```
$array1 = ($arr1);
$array2 = ($arr2);
$result = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

What am I doing wrong?  This is the result that I am looking for:

```
Array(
    [Nov 18, 2011] => Array(
        [3] => 107705.5792
        [1] => 44561.52
    )
    [Nov 22, 2011] => Array(
        [2] => -8992.8352
    )
)
```

Thanks for your help.

- EDIT -

I have found that if I instead use array_merge_recursive, this is my the result that I get.  Not what I was looking for, but close:

```
Array(
    [Nov 18, 2011] => Array(
        [C] => Array(
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 107705.5792
        )
        [I] => Array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 44561.52
        )
    )
    [Nov 22, 2011] => Array(
        [C] => Array(
            [0] => 2
            [1] => -8992.8352
        )
    )
)
```

- FURTHER EDIT -

Here is the way that I have tried to implement one of the suggestions below, however this is not working for me.  What is wrong?:

```
function cust_array_merge(array &$array1, array $array2){
    // loop through main array
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
        // check if $array2 has the same index
        if (array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
            // reset $array1's indexes to $array2's values
            foreach ($array2[$key] as $subKey => $subVal) {
                if (array_key_exists($subKey, $array1[$key])) {
                    $tempVal = $array1[$key][$subKey];
                    unset($array1[$key][$subKey]);
                    $array1[$key][$subVal] = $tempVal;}}}}}

$merged = cust_array_merge($arr_cats_per_bill_date, $arr_cvat);
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($merged);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Are you wanting to keep key references or do you not care if it becomes 0 1 2?  You can't have two keys of "C" or "I" or any other value in your array.

Comment: Why do literally **ALL** of your questions have the exact same content and arrays?  Are we doing your homework or something for school?  This is literally the _third_ or _fourth_ question of yours that I've seen in the last week or two that is almost exactly the same as the previous one..

Comment: @phpmeh, no I do not want to keep the key references.

Comment: @mmmshuddup, my questions have the same content and arrays because I am still trying to figure out the same fact situation.  This not homework for school.  I am simply trying to learn how to work with multi-dimensional arrays properly.

Comment: Gotcha. Just making sure it's not bogus in any way lol. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: It's a bit unusual to have numeric keys in an array which are not in order. Are you sure this is the best data structure you need to handle your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_merge_recursive` gets you very close (your "key" is in index 1 of leaf arrays, and your value is in index 0). So do it in two steps: first get the merged array, then fiddle with the branches to get it right.

```
// This is a callback for array_map() which should have some more generic uses.
// array(array('k', 'v'), ...) -> array('k' => 'v', ...)
function flatten_branches($branches) {
    $newleaves = array();
    foreach ($branches as $leaf) {
        $newleaves[$leaf[0]] = $leaf[1];
    }
    return $newleaves;
}

function merge_flatten_branches($karray, $varray) {
    //$karray has the key-leaves, and $varray has the value-leaves
    $m1 = array_merge_recursive($karray, $varray);
    return array_map('flatten_branches', $m1);
}

$merged = merge_flatten_branches($array2, $array1);
print_r($merged);
```

Just for fun, here are two more approaches. Both of these are a bit slower than `merge_flatten_branches`, but illustrate some useful array concepts. (In other more functional-flavored languages than php, these might be preferred.)

```
function merge_flatten_branches_reduce($karray, $varray) {
    //$karray has the key-leaves, and $varray has the value-leaves
    $m1 = array_merge_recursive($karray, $varray);
    return array_map('flatten_branches_reduce', $m1);
}

function merge_flatten_branches_add($karray, $varray) {
    //$karray has the key-leaves, and $varray has the value-leaves
    $m1 = array_merge_recursive($karray, $varray);
    return array_map('flatten_branches_add', $m1);
}

// The functions below are callbacks for the two above.

function array_add($a1, $a2) {
    return $a1+$a2;
}

function flatten_leaf($leaf) {
    return array($leaf[0] => $leaf[1]);
}

function flatten_branches_add($branches) {
    $leaves = array_map('flatten_leaf', ($branches));
    $finalleaves = array();
    foreach ($leaves as $leaf) {
        $finalleaves += $leaf;
    }
    return $finalleaves;
}


function flatten_branches_reduce($branches) {
    $l = array_map('flatten_leaf', ($branches));
    return array_reduce($l, 'array_add', array());
}
```

Comment: This is very cool Francis.  Your solutions were spot-on.  Exactly the result I was looking for.  Now I just need to wrap my head around how it was done.  Many thanks.

Comment: Wrap your head around _how it was done_? I, on the other hand, am just trying to understand what the heck is terminology is supposed to mean. All that `flatten_leaf` stuff is rather esoteric. Cryptic function names...not cool.  If this was a clever, yet meaningless, function name contest, `merge_flatten_branches_reduce` would win with flying colours lol.  Nevertheless, +1 for a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

The result you're looking for looks really custom to me. That is to say, I don't know of any built-in PHP array functions that would do *that*.  However, I did write a custom function for you. **Warning**: it is very tailored to this occasion and thus probably not very *reusable*.

```
function cust_array_merge(array $array1, array $array2)
{
    $merged = array();
    // loop through main array
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
        // check if $array2 has the same index
        if (array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
            // reset $array1's indexes to $array2's values
            foreach ($array2[$key] as $subKey => $subVal) {
                if (array_key_exists($subKey, $array1[$key])) {
                    $tempVal = $array1[$key][$subKey];
                    unset($array1[$key][$subKey]);
                    $array1[$key][$subVal] = $tempVal;
                }
            }
            $merged = $array1;
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm having trouble implementing it.  I have edited my question to show you what I have tried so far.  Can you see what I have done wrong?

Comment: The `cust_array_merge` function doesn't actually return anything. The first argument it accepts (`$array1`) is by _reference_ (hence the `&`).

Comment: I changed it so it would return the merged array now. Check out my edited function and that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @mmmshuddup.  I got your solution to work, and in the process learned a thing or two.  That's very cool that you did that for me.  Made my day.  Cheers.

Comment: I did notice that your result rounded the numbers to the nearest whole number, rather than keeping the decimal precision.  Don't worry about fixing it because the other answer posted also works, and maintains the decimal precision.