# Merging multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge

I have an array in PHP with this structure:

```
Array
(
  [7] => Array
    (
      [6] => Array
        (
          [200000000] => Array
            (
              [201000001] => Array
                (
                  [201000002] => Entry
                  [201000003] => History
                  [201000004] => Statistic
                  [201000005] => Edit
                )

            )

        )

      [7] => Array
        (
          [200000000] => Array
            (
              [201000001] => Array
                (
                  [201000002] => Entry
                  [201000005] => Edit
                )

              [201000006] => Request
              [201000007] => Array
                (
                  [201000008] => Array
                    (
                      [201000009] => Inbox
                      [201000010] => Cancellation
                    )

                )

            )

        )

    )

)
```

how can I turn that array into something like this:

```
Array
(
  [7] => Array
    (
      [6] => Array
        (
          [200000000] => Array
            (
              [201000001] => Array
                (
                  [201000002] => Entry
                  [201000003] => History
                  [201000004] => Statistic
                  [201000005] => Edit
                )

              [201000006] => Request
              [201000007] => Array
                (
                  [201000008] => Array
                    (
                      [201000009] => Inbox
                      [201000010] => Cancellation
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Preferable if there is PHP built-in function that can do that? Or maybe a function with not to much loop?

Thank you before ...

Comment: this already posted. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381439/php-combine-two-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: i've tried that, but seems not the one i'm looking for (since i just have one array variable). as you can see, i need to merge the same index, but the other index that has difference need to merge separately... doing it with + operator almost merge them, except the different keys aren't merge...

Comment: i've found function in kohana framework that i can use:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Arr#merge
seems that's what i'm looking for...