# Merging/grouping multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I currently have two arrays that look like so, that I've been trying to group/merge but have had no luck.

`$array1;`

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [options] => 1
            [barcode] => 
            [supplier] => 10
            [topcat] => Fibre,1
            [cat] => Acrylic,1
            [range] => Clearance Chenille,14
            [colour] => 
            [type] => Ball
            [option] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Ball
                            [barcode] => 
                            [length] => 
                            [wpi] => 
                            [dyeable] => 
                            [feltable] => 
                            [sold_weight] => 
                            [gauge] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [pack_qty] => 
                            [shipping_weight] => 
                            [cost_price] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [options] => 1
            [barcode] => 
            [supplier] => 10
            [topcat] => Fibre,1
            [cat] => Acrylic,1
            [range] => Clearance Chenille,14
            [colour] => 
            [type] => Ball
            [option] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Ball
                            [barcode] => 
                            [length] => 
                            [wpi] => 
                            [dyeable] => 
                            [feltable] => 
                            [sold_weight] => 
                            [gauge] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [pack_qty] => 
                            [shipping_weight] => 
                            [cost_price] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Ball
                            [barcode] => 
                            [length] => 
                            [wpi] => 
                            [dyeable] => 
                            [feltable] => 
                            [sold_weight] => 
                            [gauge] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [pack_qty] => 
                            [shipping_weight] => 
                            [cost_price] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

`$array2;`

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 500aqua.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C70.tmp
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 133659
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 500beige.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C71.tmp
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 148940
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 500beige-zoom.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C72.tmp
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 211420
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 500beige.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C83.tmp
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 148940
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 500beige-zoom.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C84.tmp
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 211420
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I've been trying to merge them like so:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [options] => 1
            [barcode] => 
            [supplier] => 10
            [topcat] => Fibre,1
            [cat] => Acrylic,1
            [range] => Clearance Chenille,14
            [colour] => 
            [type] => Ball
            [option] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Ball
                            [barcode] => 
                            [length] => 
                            [wpi] => 
                            [dyeable] => 
                            [feltable] => 
                            [sold_weight] => 
                            [gauge] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [pack_qty] => 
                            [shipping_weight] => 
                            [cost_price] => 
                            [files] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => 500aqua.jpg
                                            [type] => image/jpeg
                                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C70.tmp
                                            [error] => 0
                                            [size] => 133659
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [options] => 1
            [barcode] => 
            [supplier] => 10
            [topcat] => Fibre,1
            [cat] => Acrylic,1
            [range] => Clearance Chenille,14
            [colour] => 
            [type] => Ball
            [option] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Ball
                            [barcode] => 
                            [length] => 
                            [wpi] => 
                            [dyeable] => 
                            [feltable] => 
                            [sold_weight] => 
                            [gauge] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [pack_qty] => 
                            [shipping_weight] => 
                            [cost_price] => 
                            [files] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => 500beige.jpg
                                            [type] => image/jpeg
                                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C71.tmp
                                            [error] => 0
                                            [size] => 148940
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => 500beige-zoom.jpg
                                            [type] => image/jpeg
                                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C72.tmp
                                            [error] => 0
                                            [size] => 211420
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Ball
                            [barcode] => 
                            [length] => 
                            [wpi] => 
                            [dyeable] => 
                            [feltable] => 
                            [sold_weight] => 
                            [gauge] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [pack_qty] => 
                            [shipping_weight] => 
                            [cost_price] => 
                            [files] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => 500beige.jpg
                                            [type] => image/jpeg
                                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C83.tmp
                                            [error] => 0
                                            [size] => 148940
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => 500beige-zoom.jpg
                                            [type] => image/jpeg
                                            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6C84.tmp
                                            [error] => 0
                                            [size] => 211420
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Currently getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Ball
                    [barcode] => 
                    [length] => 
                    [wpi] => 
                    [dyeable] => 
                    [feltable] => 
                    [sold_weight] => 
                    [gauge] => 
                    [price] => 
                    [pack_qty] => 
                    [shipping_weight] => 
                    [cost_price] => 
                )

            [files] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 500aqua.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php1534.tmp
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 133659
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Ball
                    [barcode] => 
                    [length] => 
                    [wpi] => 
                    [dyeable] => 
                    [feltable] => 
                    [sold_weight] => 
                    [gauge] => 
                    [price] => 
                    [pack_qty] => 
                    [shipping_weight] => 
                    [cost_price] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Ball
                    [barcode] => 
                    [length] => 
                    [wpi] => 
                    [dyeable] => 
                    [feltable] => 
                    [sold_weight] => 
                    [gauge] => 
                    [price] => 
                    [pack_qty] => 
                    [shipping_weight] => 
                    [cost_price] => 
                )

            [files] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 500beige.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php1535.tmp
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 148940
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 500beige-zoom.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php1545.tmp
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 211420
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 500beige.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php1546.tmp
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 148940
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 500beige-zoom.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php1547.tmp
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 211420
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What I've tried so far:

```
$group = array();
foreach($array1 as $key1 => $val1){
    $group[] = array_merge($val1, array("files" => $array2[$key1]));
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381439/php-combine-two-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: Can you post a simpler example input/output that shows why array_merge($array1, $array2) will not work?

Comment: Yeah, updated the OP to show what I currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not yet tested it (I may have some time in about an hour), but I think this may help:

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $val){
   foreach($val['option'] as $k_inner => $v_inner){
      $array1[$key]['option'][$k_inner]['files'] = $array2[$key][$k_inner];
   }
}
```

You will have array2 being your `$group` array. As soon as I test it, I'll edit this.

EDIT: Corrected algorithm. The mistaked layed in the fact that I mixed up $array1 and $array2 and that I was not considering the correct deepness and keys.

Comment: Could you please send me the arrays so I can do the testing? sikian @ gmail . com

Comment: The arrays are created using POST parameters. You can convert the `print_r` arrays using http://phpoverflow.eu01.aws.af.cm/print_r/ http://codepad.org/EmdBkpum

Comment: Oh, thanks! Just learnt something.
Well, let's try some solutions.

Comment: Well, it seems it's now working. I've updated my solution, and they are running correctly for me.

Btw, the array that you sent me had some small mistakes in deepness.

Comment: Thank you, it works when there's 1 part of the array that needs merging but breaks when it tries to merge 2. http://codepad.org/bJiq7MdL